# How come Wanda can overpower Vision?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america-civil-war

As far as I understood, Wanda's power are coming from the mind stone, as J.A.R.V.I.S told her so, when they were talking about the mind stone in the kitchen.

But there is a scene afterward, that he tries to keep Wanda from leaving, but she easily overpowers Vision.

My question is, how can she do that, when her powers *"came"* from the mind stone, while vision is actually carrying the mind stone itself?

Comment: Vision is far from being in full control of the Mind Stone: "I don't know what this is. Not really. I know it's not of this world. That it powered Loki's staff, gave you your abilities. But... its true nature is a mystery."

Answer (score 8):

## Because Vision let her

As in your question, Vision only tries to keep Wanda by reasoning with her. He even tries to make her favorite dish. (*something called **Paprikash** if memory serves me right*) and tried to talk to her. Vision never wanted to force her, neither use his power against her. He just tried to make her understand by reasoning with her. He has some sort of feelings (considering he is android). See the dialog between them below.

> **Vision**: "Wanda."
>
> **Wanda**: "Hmm?"
>
> **Vision**: "No one dislikes you, Wanda."
>
> **Wanda**: "...Thanks."
>
> **Vision**: "Oh, you're welcome. No. It's a...
>    involuntary response in their amygdala they can't help but be afraid of you."
>
> **Wanda**: "Are you?"
>
> **Vision**: "My amygdala is synthetic, so..."
>
> **Vision**: "I used to think of myself one way. But, after this. I am something else. And still me, I think. But... that's not what everyone else sees."

He only tried to reason with her, but when Clint came for Wanda and made her stop Vision, he just let her. Mainly because of his feelings towards her. Vision even displayed his feeling towards her after this scene

Comment: But Barton told him, that _"I can't, but she can"_ ( referring to who can overpower vision )

Comment: @JackJohansson Yes, I think he refers that both may have same source for power, From two of them (Clint and Wanda) only Wanda can fight back with Vision's powers. We saw that being mere human, Barton can't give Vision a good fight with vision's abilities and powers. Saying that, he motivated Wanda to get free and what Wanda did, made vision surprised and distracted

Comment: The extend of Wanda's powers are drastically different in the MCU after wandavision. The new theory is that her powers did not come from the stone, rather the stone somehow helped her to channelize it.

Comment: @CyriacAntony It's interesting, do you have any sources? I'd like to read more about that

Comment: The show wandavision itself is the source. Even before coming into contact with the mind stone, she involuntarily used probability hex in an attempt to disable the missile. I suppose probability hex is a part of chaos magic (it is in the comics). 

In the show Agatha says "the scarlet witch is not born, she is forged" and that the scarlet witch is suppose to destroy the world. The fact that Darkhold has an entire chapter dedicated to Scarlet witch is alarming.

Comment: Here is one [unofficial article](https://www.cinemablend.com/television/2564868/why-scarlet-witchs-powers-looked-different-in-wandavision-than-they-did-in-the-mcu-movies). The [official page](https://www.marvel.com/characters/scarlet-witch-wanda-maximoff/on-screen) says "The full extent of Wanda’s considerable powers has likely not been fully documented as of yet" and that her powers come at least in part from the mind stone.